# How to detect specific subwords in text

Tags: regex, stata

I have a column as a string with no spaces:

```
clear
input str100 var
"ihaveanewspaper"
"watchingthenewsonthetv"
"watchthenewsandreadthenewspaper"
end
```

I am using the following command:

```
gen = regex,(var, "(news)")
```

This outputs `1 1 1` because it finds that the `3` rows in the column `var` contain the word news.

I'm trying to alter the regular expression `"(news)"` to create two columns. One for news and one for newspaper. `regexm(var, "(newspaper)")` makes sure that the row contains a newspaper, but I need a command to make sure characters after news are not "paper" as I'm trying to quantify the two.

---

**EDIT:**

Is there a way to count the third entry as `1`, because it has a `news` occurrence without however being a newspaper?

Comment: The "following command" is illegal. Few users of Stata will not realise that, but it's not good practice to give illegal commands as examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quantify as follows without a regular expression:

```
clear
input str100 var
"ihaveanewspaper"
"watchingthenewsonthetv"
"watchthenewsandreadthenewspaper"
"fdgdnews"
"fgogodigjhoigjnewspaper"
"fgeogeionnewsfgdgfpaper"
"45pap9358newsfjfgni"
end

generate news = strmatch(var, "*news*") & !strmatch(var, "*newspaper*")

list, separator(0)

     +----------------------------------------+
     |                             var   news |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |                 ihaveanewspaper      0 |
  2. |          watchingthenewsonthetv      1 |
  3. | watchthenewsandreadthenewspaper      0 |
  4. |                        fdgdnews      1 |
  5. |         fgogodigjhoigjnewspaper      0 |
  6. |         fgeogeionnewsfgdgfpaper      1 |
  7. |             45pap9358newsfjfgni      1 |
     +----------------------------------------+

count if news
4

count if !news
3
```

---

**EDIT:**

One way to do this is to eliminate all instances of the word `newspaper` and repeat the process:

```
generate var2 = subinstr(var, "newspaper", "", .)
replace news = 1 if strmatch(var2, "*news*")

list, separator(0)

     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                             var   news                      var2 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                 ihaveanewspaper      0                    ihavea |
  2. |          watchingthenewsonthetv      1    watchingthenewsonthetv |
  3. | watchthenewsandreadthenewspaper      1    watchthenewsandreadthe |
  4. |                        fdgdnews      1                  fdgdnews |
  5. |         fgogodigjhoigjnewspaper      0            fgogodigjhoigj |
  6. |         fgeogeionnewsfgdgfpaper      1   fgeogeionnewsfgdgfpaper |
  7. |             45pap9358newsfjfgni      1       45pap9358newsfjfgni |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------+

count if news
5

count if !news
2
```